# How can I force CMake to use Python executables and libs from a given folder?

Tags: python, cmake, pybind11

I have both Python 3.6 in "C:\PYTHON_VERSIONS\STANDARD_3.6.8" and 3.8 in "C:\Python\3.8" in my system. I want to compile pybind11 using 3.6 but CMake takes lib directories from 3.6 and the executable from 3.8! a very bad mix indeed.

Here is output of CMake:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python/3.8/python.exe (found version "3.8.9") 
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python/3.8/python.exe (found suitable version "3.8.9", minimum required is "3.6") 
CMake Error at C:/work/packgen/rsdist/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:147 (message):
  Python config failure:

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
    File "C:\PYTHON_VERSIONS\STANDARD_3.6.8\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 14, in <module>
      import re
    File "C:\PYTHON_VERSIONS\STANDARD_3.6.8\lib\re.py", line 123, in <module>
      import sre_compile
    File "C:\PYTHON_VERSIONS\STANDARD_3.6.8\lib\sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
      assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"

  AssertionError: SRE module mismatch

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package)
```

I have in my environment variables PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH to the 3.6 folder:
[image]

And in the "path" variable itself there are no paths to any of the python installation folders.

So the question is: How does CMake finds executable that is not in the path, and mixes executable and libs of different versions?

Is there something like `CMAKE_SET_PYTHON_PATH` or something that I force feed it into CMake?

Comment: what _exactly_ did you try with `Python_ROOT_DIR`? Show a [mre] of your attempt.

Comment: I passed it to cmake command like `-DPython_ROOT_DIR=C:\PYTHON_VERSIONS\STANDARD_3.6.8`

Comment: what shell did you do that in? In some shells, you might need to escape those backslashes.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you can do is consider specifying a version constraint in [the `find_package` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#basic-signature) call.

Besides that, [the FindPython module has some hints variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html#hints), which you can try using. Of particular interest is probably `Python_ROOT_DIR`. Quoting from the docs:

> `Python_ROOT_DIR`:
> Define the root directory of a Python installation.

You could try setting that as a cache variable in your configure command using [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D). Ex `-DPython_ROOT_DIR=C:\PYTHON_VERSIONS\STANDARD_3.6.8`.

You might also be interested in the `Python_FIND_ABI` and `Python_FIND_STRATEGY` hint variables. If you want the latest version in the fitting search locations to be used, then set `Python_FIND_STRATEGY` to `VERSION`.

See also [the corresponding docs if you're using the `FindPython3` module instead of the `FindPython` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#hints) (and make sure to adjust the hint variable names accordingly if this is the case).

Comment: I tried the Python_root_dir but it didnt change anything :(